# Change Default d3.js colors

Tags: d3.js

I was looking for a way to change the default colors of the different categories in d3.js.

I found where the colors are laid out in the main d3.js. They look like this for one category:

```
var ml = [2062260, 16744206, 2924588, 14034728, 9725885, 9197131, 14907330, 8355711, 12369186, 1556175].map(yt)
```

I've tried replacing these values with everything from Hex codes to HSL to RGB and it never yields the expected colors.

Any ideas how I can generate the proper numbers for whatever colors I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just FYI, to see the RGB (i.e. hex) value that corresponds to these numbers:

```
(2062260).toString(16); // 16 for hex, aka base 16
> "1f77b4"
```

Next, given an RGB (again, hex) that you want to convert to number:

```
parseInt("1f77b4", 16); // 16 for hex
> 2062260
```

And that would be the number you want to use.

The colors you got from the d3 source are used to construct what you get from `d3.scale.category10()`. You can get the same thing but with your own colors — and without modifying d3's source code — by constructing a `d3.scale.ordinal`:

```
var myCategory3 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["red", "#1f77b4", "rgb(128, 255, 128)"]);// All kinds of colors are possible

myCategory3("X");// "red"
myCategory3("blabla");// "#1f77b4"
myCategory3("X");// "red"
myCategory3(123456);// "rgb(128, 255, 128)"
```

Comment: Thanks...that's exactly what I need. Couldn't figure out how to convert it. Appreciate the help.